Can emacs directly edit a null delimited file?
Editing files which use the null byte as a line separator just like a file which uses a \012 (Linux newline) as a line would be very useful.
It would be most important that the null byte was the line separator because editing a list of raw bytes looses the ability read and edit a nice vertical list.
Is there something deep inside emacs which limits eol to be Unix or Windows and no other specified character or sequence?
If not... Do you know of any attempts to create such a mode?

The answer to the question in your title is yes - try M-x find-file-literally. I don't have an answer for the questions in your question though.

find-file-literally does not change the eol character . find-file-literrally removes automatic conversion of an existing eol style to the one you use . I did not think of it, but it would be true that If the desired eol was the null byte,  then emacs could automatically convert other forms of eol to the null byte , but  that is not what I am looking for . Gnu utilities easily create files with the  null byte as the line separator . Thanks to NickD for helping me  improve my question.
